# How can I call my hub on my controller (SignalR)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, signalr

Everytime something is posted and then added to the database, I want it to be shown on my Index.cshtml. Right now I'm doing like represented below. However this option is not working:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostIgnicoes([FromBody] Ignicoes ignicao)
    {
        **var hub = new MyHub();**
        if (ignicao.Latitude == null)
       {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    else
    {
        if (ignicao.Longitude == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        else
        {
            //if(ignicao.Estado == null)
            //{
            //    return BadRequest(ModelState);
            //}

        }
    }

    _context.Ignicoes.Add(ignicao);


    **await hub.PostMarker();**
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


    return CreatedAtAction("GetIgnicoes", new { id = ignicao.Id }, ignicao);
}
```

But everytime I post something it return an error 500, which mean I can't post anything. Why does this happen?

Comment: To ask the dumb question: have you put a breakpoint at `await hub.PostMarker()` and used that to inspect the actual exception that's being thrown?

Comment: Yes. It's thown this exception "System.NullReferenceException". Maybe it's because this line `var hub = new MyHub();`. But I'm not sure how to call the hub.

Comment: I'm relatively certain that you aren't supposed to use the Hubs that way. I have a basic implementation of a notifications hub that I could try explaining, if that helps.

Comment: please, if you don't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I understood SignalR to work. There may be more to it, but building something similar to what I explain below enabled me to build real-time notifications into the application I'm building at the moment.

### Hub

The Hub doesn't need to have any methods defined on it in order to enable server-sent events. It's mainly a hook for the other SignalR components that you wire up. So, let's create a mostly empty Hub, which I'll call MapHub:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace YourApplicationNamespace
{
    public class MapHub : Hub
    {
    }
}
```

That's it. Seems odd, but let's continue.

### `IHubContext<T>`

This is actually what you would use to send a notification to registered clients. You would register this in your Startup (or wherever your DI container is configured). This is done for you when you use something similar to:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapHub<MapHub>("/notify"); 
});
```

`"/notify"` is the endpoint I'm going to use for this hub. It's what SignalR will use to register clients.

Then, update your controller, and add `IHubContext<MapHub>` as a dependency:

```
public class MapsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MapHub> hubContext;

    public MapsController(IHubContext<MapHub> hubContext)
    {
        this.hubContext = hubContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hubContext));
    }

    // ... the rest of your code

}
```

Once that's done, you'll modify your action.

### Notify clients to get data

Rather than call

```
**await hub.PostMarker();**
```

you'll do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostIgnicoes([FromBody] Ignicoes ignicao)
{
    if (ignicao.Latitude == null)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    else
    {
        if (ignicao.Longitude == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }

    _context.Ignicoes.Add(ignicao);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // THIS IS THE NEW SIGNALR CODE
    await hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("getMarkers");

    return CreatedAtAction("GetIgnicoes", new { id = ignicao.Id }, ignicao);
}
```

Notice that you don't directly use the Hub - that class is primarily for the bits that get wired up for you via the `.MapHub` extension in Startup and the JavaScript code we haven't talked about yet.

`Clients.All.SendAsync("getMarkers")` tells SignalR to send a notification to all registered clients and triggers the event `getMarkers` (defined below).

### Client Setup

I'm going to assume you already have the SignalR client scripts downloaded and loaded on the page. The code below is how I setup my connection:

```
try {
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('/notify')
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Warning)
        .build();

    connection.on('getMarkers', function () {
        // ADD CODE HERE TO REQUEST NEW MARKERS
    });

    connection.start().then(function () {
        console.log("Hub connected");
    });
}
catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

That's more or less cookie-cutter from the SignalR tutorials on Microsoft Docs. The key part is

```
    connection.on('getMarkers', function () {
        // ADD CODE HERE
    });
```

That's how you setup the "listening" endpoint for your clients, which is the endpoint called by `hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("getMarkers")` (in my example). What you do at `// ADD CODE HERE` is up to you. My instance uses jQuery's $.load function to reload a sidebar on my page.

Answer (score 1):

In SignalR, a Hub is basically the collection of “methods” that a client can call. So this is the interface the client works with, just like a controller would work for a web API.

If you want to call methods on the clients, then using the hub is not the right approach. Instead, you want to use the `IHubContext`. You will need to inject that into your controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MyHub> _hubContext;

    public HomeController(IHubContext<MyHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostIgnicoes([FromBody] Ignicoes ignicao)
    {
        //…

        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("PostMarker");
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        //…
    }
}
```

For more details, check out the documentation on [sending messages from outside a hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1). You can also this with use [strongly typed hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1#strongly-typed-hubs) to avoid having to call untyped methods by passing their name as a string.